# Issues in response return by OLA API of cabs availability and estimation in sandbox environment

Tags: sandbox, availability

I am trying to integrate Ola api of cabs availability and estimation in sandbox environment.As per ola documentation, they have created virtual cabs for sandbox environment in KR Puram, Bengaluru, India (Lat: 13.0040167, Lng: 77.6877765) and
Orion Mall, Bengaluru, India (Lat: 13.0107881, Lng: 77.5527122).but when I fired the request with their request url and other header data
(x-app-token,authorization), it doesn't return available cabs data in response.I am using postman for this purpose.Please revert with some solution.

**request URL**

http://sandbox-t.olacabs.com//v1/products?pickup_lat=13.0040167&pickup_lng=77.6877765&drop_lat=13.0107881&drop_lng=77.5527122&service_type=&category=micro

**Response return**

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "micro",
            "display_name": "Micro",
            "currency": "INR",
            "distance_unit": "kilometer",
            "time_unit": "minute",
            "eta": -1,
            "distance": -1,
            "ride_later_enabled": "true",
            "ride_later_allowed": true,
            "ride_now_allowed": false,
            "image": "http://d1foexe15giopy.cloudfront.net/micro.png",
            "cancellation_policy": {
                "cancellation_charge": 25,
                "currency": "INR",
                "cancellation_charge_applies_after_time": 5,
                "time_unit": "minute"
            },
            "fare_breakup": [
                {
                    "type": "flat_rate",
                    "minimum_distance": 2,
                    "minimum_time": 1,
                    "base_fare": "60.0",
                    "minimum_fare": "0.0",
                    "cost_per_distance": "9.0",
                    "waiting_cost_per_minute": 0,
                    "ride_cost_per_minute": "1.5",
                    "surcharge": [],
                    "rates_lower_than_usual": false,
                    "rates_higher_than_usual": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "flat_rate",
                    "minimum_distance": 0,
                    "minimum_time": 0,
                    "base_fare": "90.0",
                    "minimum_fare": "225.0",
                    "cost_per_distance": "9.0",
                    "waiting_cost_per_minute": 0,
                    "ride_cost_per_minute": "1.5",
                    "surcharge": [],
                    "rates_lower_than_usual": false,
                    "rates_higher_than_usual": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "flat_rate",
                    "minimum_distance": 0,
                    "minimum_time": 0,
                    "base_fare": "90.0",
                    "minimum_fare": "225.0",
                    "cost_per_distance": "10.5",
                    "waiting_cost_per_minute": 0,
                    "ride_cost_per_minute": "1.5",
                    "surcharge": [],
                    "rates_lower_than_usual": false,
                    "rates_higher_than_usual": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "flat_rate",
                    "minimum_distance": 0,
                    "minimum_time": 0,
                    "base_fare": "90.0",
                    "minimum_fare": "225.0",
                    "cost_per_distance": "9.0",
                    "waiting_cost_per_minute": 0,
                    "ride_cost_per_minute": "3.0",
                    "surcharge": [],
                    "rates_lower_than_usual": false,
                    "rates_higher_than_usual": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ride_estimate": [
        {
            "category": "micro",
            "distance": 21.94,
            "travel_time_in_minutes": 50,
            "amount_min": 323,
            "amount_max": 340,
            "discounts": {
                "discount_type": "discount",
                "discount_code": "RANDOM",
                "discount_mode": "AUTO",
                "discount": 5,
                "cashback": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "previous_cancellation_charges": []
}
```

**Expected response should contain cab availability data as follows:(refer from ola documentation)**

```
"all_cabs": [{                        // Current locations of nearby cabs
            "lat": 12.9543501,
            "lng": 77.5438193,
            "id":"e0e7ba15f7249207c1d77ec07c1c06",
            "bearing":534,
            "accuracy":15
      },
      {
            "lat": 12.9561008,
            "lng": 77.5464725,
            "id":"15f7249207c1d77e9207c1c0601d6c9c",
            "bearing":135,
            "accuracy":10
      }]
    }],
```